# Creating route and adding that route as layer to map using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, linear-referencing, route

I wrote a little script for ArcGis, and when I make it run by GUI it happens that it seems to create routes but the routes do not appear in the TOC.

Consequently, when the script tries to execute operation on those routes, the dataset cannot be found.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide some details of your code, please?

Comment: Posting your code might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested the code below which seemed to work when I placed it behind a tool with no parameters.

```
arcpy.CreateRoutes_lr("C:/temp/test.gdb/Streets","STREET","C:/temp/test.gdb/StreetRoutes","LENGTH","#","#","UPPER_LEFT","1","0","IGNORE","INDEX")

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/temp/test.gdb/StreetRoutes", "route_lyr")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("route_lyr", "C:/temp/StreetRoutes.lyr")
addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:/temp/StreetRoutes.lyr")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)
```

MakeRouteEventLayer is for placing line and point events along routes so is not used as part of simply drawing the route.

Comment: many thanks, it seems to work (makes a route event layer) evenif it doesn't seems to add the created route to the TOC. Quite strange, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with ArcPy.mapping:

```
# Project variables
arcpy.env.workspace = "[Your working directory]"
mapTemplate = "ModelDepDM.mxd"
lyrZones = "__Zone500_Rabat_DM"

# Mxd and dataframe
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, mapTemplate))
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

# What I'd like to add
newSource = os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace, lyrZones[0:-3] + _dirNum + ".shp")
result = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(newSource, lyrZones)

# Adding the result to the TOC
layer2 = result.getOutput(0)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer2, 'AUTO_ARRANGE')
```

You need to make a feature layer from your result and add it to a dataframe.

Maybe there's another way to do it, but it works for me...

Comment: This script does not look like it creates routes so I am going to ask @Annalisa Minelli for more details of her code.

Comment: That's the part to add a layer to a TOC... According to Annalisa, her script creates the routes, but don't add them to the TOC...

Comment: I wanted to check what tools she used to "create" her routes.  For example, she may not have followed the tips [**here**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Adding_route_events_using_the_Linear_Referencing_toolbox/003900000029000000/)

Comment: thanks @fgcartographix , I've got no data at the moment, but I'll try your suggestion as soon as possible.
PolyGeo : I created the routes using arpcy.CreateRoutes_lr. Then I have to place some points on the routes, starting from a table. So I used the "MakeRouteEventLayer_lr", but, at that point, the command doesn't find the routes.

Comment: @fgcartographix : I cannot understand what is the "newSource" since lyrZones seems not to be a list and the route is not produced in ".shp" format..

Comment: Oups! Sorry. newSource is just a variable containing a string for the name of the feature layer. I copy pasted the part of my script that add the FL to my TOC but forgot to define that variable.

Comment: @PolyGeo : the code into my script executes the commands below

`arcpy.CreateRoutes_lr("vectorline","FID","provaroute","LENGTH","","","LOWER_LEFT")
arcpy.AddMessage("route created")   arcpy.MakeRouteEventLayer_lr("provaroute","FID","tableView","ID POINT MEAS","pointRoute.shp")`


I placed the "AddMessage" just to verify that the command "CreateRoutes" works and I had really no problem with it - the problem is in the "MakeRouteEventLayer". Many thanks..